# git unable to open connection

Tags: git, github, ssh, connection

ssh cant connect to GitHub, but git clone occurs unable to open connection. How can I resolve it?
when I use puttygen generate PPK, I can git clone code by tortoisegit.

> git version 2.24.1.windows.2
>   TortoiseGit 2.9.0.0 (C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin)

```
$ ssh -vvvT git@github
OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/zhangv/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/zhangv/.ssh/config line 10: Applying options for github
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to github [13.229.188.59] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/zhangv/.ssh/github type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/zhangv/.ssh/github-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-778045a0
debug1: no match: babeld-778045a0
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/zhangv/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/zhangv/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/zhangv/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/zhangv/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/zhangv/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/zhangv/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 13.229.188.59
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/zhangv/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/zhangv/.ssh/github RSA SHA256:LqTnOkYIC/he5tZh5m2ADFfM7d50gIV6eAOzYEBDomM explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/zhangv/.ssh/github RSA SHA256:LqTnOkYIC/he5tZh5m2ADFfM7d50gIV6eAOzYEBDomM explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /c/Users/zhangv/.ssh/github RSA SHA256:LqTnOkYIC/he5tZh5m2ADFfM7d50gIV6eAOzYEBDomM explicit
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:LqTnOkYIC/he5tZh5m2ADFfM7d50gIV6eAOzYEBDomM
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([13.229.188.59]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x20
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 89
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf_empty delayed efd 6/(89)
Hi zhangvv! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug2: channel 0: written 89 to efd 6
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r43 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3104, received 2356 bytes, in 0.8 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4018.7, received 3050.3
debug1: Exit status 1
```

I cann't git clone my code on github.

```
$ git clone git@github:zhangvv/shadowsocksr-csharp.git
Cloning into 'shadowsocksr-csharp'...
Unable to open connection:
Host does not existfatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Below is .ssh/config.

```
# github
Host github
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
```

Comment: There're too many colons in the URL, it must be `git clone git@github:zhangvv/shadowsocksr-csharp.git`

Comment: sorry,I misspelled it and I revised the question.git clone git@github:zhangvv/shadowsocksr-csharp.git will make the same mistake.

Comment: Let's debug: try `git clone git@github.com:zhangvv/shadowsocksr-csharp.git`, then `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -vvv' git clone git@github:zhangvv/shadowsocksr-csharp.git`

Comment: "Host does not existfatal: Could not read from remote repository." See if you have CTRL-M characters in your .ssh/config file, particularly at the end of the HostName line.

Comment: **I solved the problem,Modify the windows system environment variables**,`GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`[link](https://blog.csdn.net/cen_cs/article/details/80075953)