# ssh with 2 accounts in gitlab doesn't work

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, config

I'm trying to add 2 ssh keys in my pc to work with 2 gitlab accounts, I created 2 pair of keys and made this "config" file:

```
# Compte Perso
Host gitlab.com-perso
   HostName gitlab.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile C:\Users\<path>\.ssh\id_rsa_perso

# Compte Pro
Host gitlab.com
   HostName gitlab.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile C:\Users\<path>\.ssh\id_rsa
```

When I type `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` and `ssh -T git@gitlab.com-perso`, it works I have the output `Wlecome to Gitlab, <username>!`, but when I try to clone like this `git clone git@gitlab.com-perso:<username>/<reponame>.git`

it says

```
Unable to open connection:
Host does not existfatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I know the repo can be cloned because I already cloned it in another pc with ssh but I don't understand why this doesn't work please help me.
I have followed [this](https://thibautsoufflet.fr/blog/utiliser-plusieurs-comptes-gitlab-et-cles-ssh/) to make my config file. (it's in french)

Comment: Double check your repo name. Make sure you copy it correctly

Comment: @MadPhysicist The error is `Host does not exist`: I suspect this is not about the repository name, but the SSH config `Host` entry.

Comment: Can you confirm `ssh -T ...` logs you in as different user? because usually it doesn't. The common solution is to add `IdentitiesOnly yes` to the host definitions.

Comment: @bdecaf ssh -T gives right accounts in both situations, but I'll try IdentitiesOnly thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=li:1&q=Unable+to+open+connection%3A+Host+does+not+existfatal%3A+Could+not+read+from+remote+repository.) search for your error message reveals that this problem may be related to "Little Snitch" software - if you use it disable and try again.

Also, on Windows machines you may need to modify windows system environment variables

`GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`

as you can see in [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525385/git-unable-to-open-connection)

If none of this works, there are couple of other ideas out there. It's a good idea to try at least couple of them and collect some more verbose output so we can help you better if still needed.

Comment: thanks I'll try this too and I come back

Answer (score 1):

First, you can add `User git` in each of your entries. That way, you can use `gitlab.com-perso:<usernassh -T git@gitlab.com-persome>/<reponame>.git` without the `git@`

Second, make sure `ssh -T git@gitlab.com-perso` return the right account, because if seems from your question both return the same username.

```
Host does not exist
```

Double check your host entry: gitlab.com-perso should use the right '-': you might have used a  '—' (a [long dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)) instead of the expected [double hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) (or [hyphen-minus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/170148/6309)).

Comment: ssh -T gives the right accounts

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @Lukasz Korbasiewicz and @bdecaf I added `IdentitiesOnly yes` in config file `~/.ssh/config` and `GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe` in environment variables and it worked.